# Specify Column name when using ExecuteStoreQuery

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to map a returned column to a differently-named property when using `ExecuteStoreQuery`?  This leaves `Value` as `0` in both EF5 and EF6:

```
MyObject obj = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyObject>(
    "SELECT [val] = 55.0"
).Single();
```

Here's the class:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [Column("val")]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

It sets to 55, of course, if I `SELECT [Value]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature can be tracked at [Make SqlQuery (etc.) honor [Column]](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/233).  It is highly visible to the EF team, but it has not yet been implemented.

For now, however, it seems that classes have to match the SQL query result set.